# Use Arduino Libraries in AVR program

Tags: makefile, arduino, avr, atmega

I am attempting to make the transition from using a development board like the Arduino uno to programming straight to an AVR. However, the Arduino libraries as well as some 3rd party Arduino Libraries are very useful and I'd like to be able to use them but I'm having trouble adjusting the makefile to include them. Currently I'm just trying to include the "TimerOne" library I downloaded. It simply provides convenience methods for using the AVR timers and ISR's. My very simple test application just attempts to toggle the LEDs every second.

My makefile looks like this:

```
# Name: Makefile
#
# A simple program for the ATMEGA32A-PU that blinks an LED.
#

DEVICE     = atmega32
CLOCK      = 1000000
PROGRAMMER = -c avrisp 
OBJECTS    = main.o

# List any extra directories to look for include files here.
#     Each directory must be seperated by a space.
EXTRAINCDIRS = -IC:\WinAVR-20100110\avr\include\Timer1

# for ATTiny85 - unset CKDIV8
FUSES       = -U lfuse:w:0xe2:m -U hfuse:w:0xdf:m -U efuse:w:0xff:m 

# Tune the lines below only if you know what you are doing:

AVRDUDE = avrdude $(PROGRAMMER) -p $(DEVICE)
COMPILE = avr-g++ $(EXTRAINCDIRS) -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=$(CLOCK) -mmcu=$(DEVICE)

# symbolic targets:
all:  main.hex

.c.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@
.cpp.o:
    $(COMPILE) -c $< -o $@

.S.o:
    $(COMPILE) -x assembler-with-cpp -c $< -o $@
# "-x assembler-with-cpp" should not be necessary since this is the default
# file type for the .S (with capital S) extension. However, upper case
# characters are not always preserved on Windows. To ensure WinAVR
# compatibility define the file type manually.

.c.s:
    $(COMPILE) -S $< -o $@
.cpp.s:
    $(COMPILE) -S $< -o $@

flash:  all
    $(AVRDUDE) -U flash:w:main.hex:i

fuse:
    $(AVRDUDE) $(FUSES)

# Xcode uses the Makefile targets "", "clean" and "install"
install: flash fuse

# if you use a bootloader, change the command below appropriately:
load: all
    bootloadHID main.hex

clean:
    rm -f main.hex main.elf $(OBJECTS)

# file targets:
main.elf: $(OBJECTS)
    $(COMPILE) -o main.elf $(OBJECTS)

main.hex: main.elf
    rm -f main.hex
    avr-objcopy -j .text -j .data -O ihex main.elf main.hex
    avr-size --format=avr --mcu=$(DEVICE) main.elf
# If you have an EEPROM section, you must also create a hex file for the
# EEPROM and add it to the "flash" target.

# Targets for code debugging and analysis:
disasm: main.elf
    avr-objdump -d main.elf

cpp:
    $(COMPILE) -E main.c
```

main.c

```
#include "TimerOne.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
void refresh();
int main(void)
{

  DDRD |= 0xff;     //Set PortD Pins as an output
  PORTD |= 0xff;    //Set PortD Pins high to turn on LEDs
  Timer1.initialize(1000000); // 1000000us = 1s
  Timer1.attachInterrupt(refresh);

  while(1) { }          //Loop forever, interrupts do the rest
}

void refresh()
{
    PORTD ^= 0XFF;
}
```

The Error I get when I run make is:

```
avr-g++ -IC:\WinAVR-20100110\avr\include\Timer1 -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=1000000 -mmcu=atmega32 -c main.c -o main.o
avr-g++ -IC:\WinAVR-20100110\avr\include\Timer1 -Wall -Os -DF_CPU=1000000 -mmcu=atmega32 -o main.elf main.o
main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x12): undefined reference to `Timer1'
main.c:(.text+0x14): undefined reference to `Timer1'
main.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `TimerOne::initialize(long)'
main.c:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `Timer1'
main.c:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `Timer1'
main.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `TimerOne::attachInterrupt(void (*)(), long)'
make: *** [main.elf] Error 1
```

From the looks of it it seems like I haven't properly told the compiler to build the TimerOne library. What am I missing?
I'm running Windows10 x64.